# Does a band logo define their music?

Tags: bands

I'm wondering, every band got logo. Even some bands that I recently see have more than one logo. Do they (the logo) represent/define their styles or character when playing their music? And what're the ideas (or what for) of more than one logo for one band?

Comment: A band's logo would only *define* their music if they thought of the logo first and then tried to write music around the logo, which I imagine is an unusual approach. I think you need to reword this a bit.

Comment: Maybe you want to ask if the logo gives us a hint about the music genre ? Like unreadable logos from black metal bands...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logo is an intrical part of the band.  Some bands, in the beginning, spend almost as much time designing their logo as they do creating the music.  It's got to be right.  It's got to define who they are, or project an image of who they want to be.

[image]

You see this, and you know **exactly** who that band is, right?  **That** is how important a logo is, particularly for branding.

[image]

Other bands want to create a certain "atmosphere" with their logo.  This is the logo for Thou Art Lord, a Black Metal band.

As you can see, logos are definitely important for branding purposes, as well as instant identification by fans and even *with* fans.

Comment: Interestingly, though I immediately knew who the first band was, the second one I couldn't even read ;)

Comment: You should see some of the "extreme" Black metal bands.  They're completely indecipherable, but they usually look like the branches of mangled trees or something.  Again, though, they're conveying more of an atmosphere by doing that.  For my answer, I picked one that was at least *somewhat* easy to read, though I didn't expect everyone would know it.

Comment: A logo is good for marketing, but there are plenty of successful bands that have no logo.

Comment: I think you mean "integral" rather than "intrical."